# Form is not checked by if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two forms with id `formA` and `comments` and I want to submit them via AJAX. But the `if` and `else` here doesn't check the form. I always get alert `hello3`.

JS:

```
function submitformbyajax() {
    var currentForm = $(this);
    if (currentForm.attr("id") == 'formA') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'commentformhandler.php',
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $("#refresh").load("commentform.php #refresh");
            }
        });
    } else if (currentForm.attr("id") == 'comments') {}
    alert("hello3");
    return false;
}
```

the function is called by

```
    <div>
    <form name="formA" id="formA" action="" method="" onsubmit="return     submitformbyajax();">
        <textarea name="comment" id="commentform" style="width:90%; height:45px;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submitbtn" />
        <input type="hidden" name="onid" value="2" id="submitbtn"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is the full demo page ....

```
<?php

?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script>
    function submitformbyajax (){
var currentForm = $(this);
  if (currentForm.attr("id") == 'formA' ) {
        $.ajax({type: 'post',
                url: 'commentformhandler.php',
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function(){
                $("#refresh").load("commentform.php #refresh");
                alert ("hello1");
                }
        } );
}
else if  (currentForm.attr("id") == 'comments') {
        alert("hello2");
    }
    alert ("hello3");
    return false;
}
</script>
    <title>
        comment forms..
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form name="formA" id="formA" action="" method="" onsubmit="return submitformbyajax();">
        <textarea name="comment" id="commentform" style="width:90%; height:45px;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submitbtn" />
        <input type="hidden" name="onid" value="2" id="submitbtn"/>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="refresh">
    <?php
        include_once('databaseconnection.php');
        $selectdata=mysql_query("select * from `fetwork_view` ");
        while($selectedinarray=mysql_fetch_array($selectdata)){ ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?=$selectedinarray['view']?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
        <form name="comment" id="comments" action="" method="">
        <textarea name="comment" id="commentform" style="width:70%; height:25px;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submitbtn" />
        <input type="hidden" name="onid" value="2" id="submitbtn"/>
        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <?php } ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to forms with the same ID.  Uses classes instead.

Comment: forms have two distinct ids formA and comments....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alert(...)` statement is executed regardless of condition tested by `if`. It is executed right after that `if`.

Note that `ajax` will not redirect the "flow" of the code. Browser will just "launch" the AJAX  request and continue. Then, after a response from server is received - AJAX callback function will be executed.

Update:

To "pass" your form to `submitformbyajax` function add `this` as an argument:

```
<form name="formA" id="formA" onsubmit="submitformbyajax(this);">
```

JS:

```
function submitformbyajax(your_form) {
    var currentForm = $(your_form);
```

Comment: form is not processing .. alert is not the problem ..problem is that the form is not processing not going inside if or else if statment...

Comment: 1. How is `submitformbyajax` called? 2. What do you see in `currentForm.attr("id")`?
Please add answer to #1 in your question.

Comment: answer is useful ... form is bow getting checked but now the value in textarea is not getting passed ...

Comment: Shouldn't you use `data: currentForm.serialize()` instead of `$("form").serialize()`?

Comment: value in the hidden field is passed and getting saved in the database but value in textarea is not passing .(value is passing for the first time only after that empty value is passed.) please help.

Comment: Seems like you have some id/name collisions, for example, you're producing >1 element with `name="comment" id="commentform"`. `id` must be unique. Otherwise - results are unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
$("form#formA").submit(function(){
  alert(1);
});
```

Comment: alert is just for checking i do not want any alert i just want that my form gets checked by if and else and then processed accordengly...